# Interpret Ruby Code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax

I want to know what the following code does in ruby, and if the same can be done in other languages?

```
def func(a)
    $i ||= -1
    eval %w(1 -1 3 6 1 1 -1 2 4 1)[$i+=1]   
end
```

I know that `$i` refers to the global variable if I'm not mistaken. But I don't know what the rest does and how I can do this in other programming languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$i ||= -1
```

This is just setting a default value. It will set `$i` to -1 if `$i` is nil, otherwise `$i` will remain unchanged.

```
eval %w(1 -1 3 6 1 1 -1 2 4 1)[$i+=1]
```

So there's a few parts here.

- `eval` will evaluate the Ruby expression in the String provided. so if you do `eval "5 + 5"`, Ruby will evaluate the string and run `5 + 5`, returning `10`.
- `%w` is a Ruby shortcut for creating a word array. It will create an array of strings from the given values. `%w(testing this)` will return `["testing", "this"]`
- `[$i+=1]` is accessing the array created by `%w`. `$i+=1` will be evaluated, adding 1 to `$1`, then accessing that element inside the array. If we have `$i = -1` and do `["testing", "this"][$i+=1]`, we will get `"testing"` back. `$i` will become 0, so we basically did `["testing", "this"][0]`, and the 0-th element is "testing"

All in all, what the function does is returns the first element in the array if $i is nil or just returns the next element in the array 
 `["1", "-1", "3", "6", "1", "1", "-1", "2", "4", "1"]`

You can easily do this in any programming language, just return the i+1 element from an array.

**Update 1**
So to do this in Python:

```
i = None
def func(a):
    global i
    if i==None:
        i = -1
    i = i + 1
    return ["1", "-1", "3", "6", "1", "1", "-1", "2", "4", "1"][i]
```

**Update 2**
In `Ruby` you use `$` to set and access global variables, in Python you have to declare a global variable in the function as `global`. Global variables are dangerous, so Ruby and Python make sure you mean to access a global variable

**Update 3**
I added `i = None` to the first update, the global variable needs to be defined

**Update 4**
If you execute the code from **Update 1** as it is, it will keep resetting `i` to `None`, you need to run `func(a)` again to return the next element

```
>>> i = None
>>> func('test')
'1'
>>> func('test')
'-1'
>>> func('test')
'3'
>>> func('test')
'6'
>>> func('test')
'1'
```

Comment: And also, why can't we say i ||= -1?

Comment: That gives me an error "global name 'i' is not defined"

Comment: But the python code only returns the first element.

Comment: The first time it's called! The Ruby code will return the first element as well. Call the function again and then it should return the second element, so on and so forth

Comment: I added another Update for you. @user120931, if your original question has been answered, if you could accept my answer [as the accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) that would be great!